# Embedding Google Assistant built on Dialogflow into my website

Tags: html, api, web, nlp, widget

I need to find a way to support our rich media like [suggestion chips](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#suggestion_chip), videos, pictures, etc into a web chat on our website as well as google assistant. Is there any software that can do this with little dev work?

Comment: What do you mean by "to support our rich media"? Just display the media? Or do you need to let users interact with it using an assistant-like widget embedded on your website?

Comment: "as well as google assistant": Do you mean you need to implement Google Assistant? Or you already have that part, and now you only want to add the same thing onto your website? It is unclear in the question so please clarify, thanks!